# Is it possible to change a document id in firestore?

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using custom classes to help structure documents fields and update, so I make sure there's no chance to have a different field name. i.e:

```
class issue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ref = firestore.client().collection("Issue").document()
        self.detail = "a"
    def create(self):
        self.ref.set({
            detail : self.detail
        })
```

So, 'someIssue = issue()' creates an object with an automatic document ID reference as 'someIssue.ref' and a string as 'someIssue.detail'. And 'someIssue.create' writes that data into Firestore using already defined docReference. 
There are many methods in my classes, like fetch() and update() for example.

What I want to do now is change this docReference to point to some other pre-existing document ID.

I tried using

```
someIssue.ref.id = <newvalue>
```

but it fails 'AttributeError: can't set attribute'

Is there any way to overwrite auto-generated docID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't change a document ID after it's been created.  You will either have to use the correct ID from the beginning, or copy the contents of the original document into a new document with the desired ID, then delete the original document.